# SharePoint 2007 passwords stop working

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-server, password

My work uses an old SharePoint 2007 site. Periodically, it will start rejecting some users' passwords, but not all. Currently, our SharePoint is linked to our Active Directory. So, it's my understanding that the users' SharePoint passwords should just be the same as our e-mail passwords, and stay that way. But that's not what is happening. Randomly, a user's password will just no longer be recognized by the site, and he/she must have it reset. I suspect it has to do with the fact that we are still using SharePoint 2007, but everything else has been migrated to Microsoft 365. Has anyone heard of anything like this before?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint dont have such thing which can stop the accepting the user's password.

Possible issues:

- check if users account's password expired?
- or User's account locked?
- once sharepoint reject the login.then restart the PC/laptop and try to login on the laptop, may give you a clue.
- what authentication method you are using?

Comment: I believe it's microsoft single sign-on. i think their passwords are expiring. Thanks for the advice!